# Jquery DataTable sorting on columns when a column is hidden

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm using Jquery DataTable and I'm facing two major problems here. If I make one of my column invisible than the sorting is getting slipped, what I mean if want  to sort a column I have to click on the column before. And my second problem how to add css id to a given column in case of class I can use `sClass:"myclassname"`. My code look as it follows

```
//===== Dynamic data table =====//

oTable = $('.dTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'data.php',
        "aoColumns": [
                      null, // the first column is invisible
                      { "bVisible": false },
                      null,
                      null,
                      null,
                      null,
                      null,
                      null,
                      null,
                      null,
                      null,
                      null,
                      null,
                      null,
                      { "bSortable": false },
                      { "bSortable": false, "sClass": "mEdit"  },
                      { "bSortable": false }                  
         ],

    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "<span class='showentries'>Show entries:</span> _MENU_"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 'add css id to each cell in  a column'? If so:

```
var colIndex = 4;

$('.dTable').children('tr').each(function(){
  $(this).children('td').eq(colIndex).css('myclassname');
});
```

As for sorting, you can set the `iDataSort` property of each column to explicitly specify the column you want the sort to data with (see here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194916/Enhancing-HTML-tables-using-a-JQuery-DataTables-pl#Sorting)